# How to filter an array without looping it?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have 30 elemements from an array

```
array:30 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "agent_id" => "958e9264-8f7d-11ea-a18a-2e2ea6f9a94a"
    "folder_name" => "2020-10-26-145338"
    "special_result" => false
    "is_special_exec" => false
    "logs_path" => "/var/log/apple/f1132f00-b8fa-11e9-85e0-0050568d2010/ue3/2020-10-26-145338"
    "logs_url" => "http://api:31004/apple/controller/v1/account/f1132f00-b8fa-11e9-85e0-0050568d2010/session/ue3/logs?path=%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fapple%2Ff1132f00-b8fa-11e9-85e0-0 ▶"
    "result" => "PASSED"
    "session_name" => "ue3"
  ]

  ...
```

I want to filter out only `"is_special_exec" => true`

I'm trying to avoid doing this

```
$specialLogs = []; 
foreach ($sessionLogs as $log) {
    if($log['special_result'] == true){
        array_push($specialLogs, $log);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do that without effect the performance ?

Comment: This is tagged Laravel; you can use Collection's `reject()` or `filter()` methods: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reject

Comment: `What is the best way to do that without effect the performance` Foreach is good enough and it can't get any more performant.

Comment: @nice_dev So if inside a foreach is okay ? compare to a filter() ?

Comment: @TimLewis I got this error `Call to a member function filter() on array`

Comment: Yes, because arrays are not Collections. You can convert an array to a collection via `collect($array)`, then use `filter()`. My comment is more-so if you already have a Collection, since most functions in Laravel return Collections instead of arrays. If you need to convert, then `array_filter` is just as performant and you can go with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$filteredArray= array_filter($sessionLogs, function ($var) {
    return ($var['special_result'] == true);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn, is what I did is really bad compare to your?

Comment: no, it 's not, but it is not the best, I made a test for the two ways, using array_filter is a little bit better in performance, but (just in my opinion) it also better in simplicity and clearness.

Comment: I don't know why you think `array_filter` is better on performance. It's shorter, but I doubt there is any difference in speed. Have you got any benchmarks?

Comment: on my computer, an array of arrays with 1000 internal array, took 559 micro second, while using array filter  took 422 micro second, I do not exactly why, if someone knows I hope he would share why

Comment: Well, for one reason, the `array_filter` is likely implemented at the C level, which makes it run faster than PHP code. I also assume it has some optimizations, like pre-allocating the result array with the size of the initial array and simply truncating it after the filtering. `array_push` on the other hand can result in lots of extra allocations and memory copying.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter those logs using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and short closures:

```
$specialLogs = array_filter($sessionLogs, fn ($log) => $log['special_result']);
```

Comment: you should mention in your answer that the method works for php 7.4 & above

Comment: Question: `I want to filter out only "is_special_exec" => true`, may be worth clarifying that.